# Foreign constraint fails for unknown reason

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table that has 3 fields that reference the same table for the 3 fields.

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_form_pago_insc`
FOREIGN KEY (`form_pago_insc` , `form_pago_tit` , `form_pago_col`)
REFERENCES `unisis`.`tbl_forma_de_pago` (`id` , `id` , `id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

This is because one field is the form of payment for the deposit, the second field is the form of payment for the course, and the third field is the form of payment for the certificate.

So all three reference the same table for foreign constraints.

I can't see any issue with this, yet I can't create it. I used MYSQL WORKBENCH to model the entire database. If I try to make a private for each one individually, MYSQL WORKBENCH closes on me. I'm using the most recent version from the website. (6.1.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want three different constraints:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_form_pago_insc` FOREIGN KEY (`form_pago_insc`)
    REFERENCES `unisis`.`tbl_forma_de_pago` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

CONSTRAINT `fk_form_pago_tit` FOREIGN KEY (`form_pago_tit`)
    REFERENCES `unisis`.`tbl_forma_de_pago` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;

CONSTRAINT `fk_form_pago_col` FOREIGN KEY (`form_pago_col`)
    REFERENCES `unisis`.`tbl_forma_de_pago` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```